# How to increase all physical abilities with magical items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, ability-scores

I have a high level crafting expert wizard with a lot of money and want to enchance my Dexterity, Strength and Constitution with magical items.

Is it right that there are only Belts <sup>[[1]](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-physical-might)[[2]](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-incredible-dexterity)[[3]](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-giant-strength)</sup> available and there is either the possibility to enhance one ability by +6 or two abilities by +4? I have found [Gloves of Dexterity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm) but only for 3.5. It there any way I can increase all physical abilities with magical items by 6 or at least 4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Traditionally the belt slot is the one that gives physical enhancement. You have More variety in belts than what you think (like for example the [Belt of Physical Perfection](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-physical-perfection) which gives bonus to all your physical attributes).

Nothing in the rules makes it impossible to get physical enhancements from items in an other slot, but I can't remember about one (besides homebrew ones). Anyway the item creation rules (which are more guidelines for the GM than real rules) suggest that such an item should be more expensive.

Comment: The Pathfinder designers deliberately changed the pricing and slots for magic items that provide an enhancement bonus to physical stats... But I can't remember why they did. There was an article about it somewhere, but I can't seem to find it any more. Maybe it was something about wanting to leave other slots open for more interesting items?

Comment: My guess is that with this system you don't have to think too much about what combination to do with your items: you want more strength? Take a belt. You want more natural armor? Take an amulet. A pernicious effect is that it means most of the other fluff items which take these slots become useless as you need these stats improvements. [These alternative rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/unchained-rules/innate-item-bonuses) seem interesting but I never actually tried them.